# How do I convert and display richtext in React?

Tags: html, json, reactjs, markdown, rich-text-editor

I'm currently undergoing a "forum-type" project. And similar to the toolbar that pops up when publishing a post here on StackOverflow + the preview of any formatting, I'd like to achieve the same on my project.

I have spent the last two days aggravating myself with draft.js and have finally managed to get the rich editor working. Meaning I can format text etc. The Problem is - although I can save the text to my database and show it in the browser - I just can't figure out how I am supposed to transfer the rich text from the client to my DB and then display it on the page.

**This is the Code I'm using to power the rich-text editor:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react"
import { EditorState } from "draft-js"
import { Editor } from "react-draft-wysiwyg"
import { convertToHTML } from "draft-convert"
import StateContext from "../StateContext"
import DispatchContext from "../DispatchContext"
import Axios from "axios"
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom"
import DOMPurify from "dompurify"
import { PreviewModal } from "./previewModal"

function TextEditor(props) {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState()
  const appDispatch = useContext(DispatchContext)
  const appState = useContext(StateContext)

  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(() => EditorState.createEmpty())
  const [convertedContent, setConvertedContent] = useState(null)
  const handleEditorChange = state => {
    setEditorState(state)
    convertContentToHTML()
  }
  const convertContentToHTML = () => {
    let currentContentAsHTML = convertToHTML(editorState.getCurrentContent())
    setConvertedContent(currentContentAsHTML)
  }
  const createMarkup = html => {
    return {
      __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(html)
    }
  }

  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
      const response = await Axios.post("/create-post", { title, body, token: appState.user.token })
      //Redirect
      appDispatch({ type: "flashMessage", value: "Congrats you created a new post!" })
      props.history.push(`/post/${response.data}`)
      console.log("new post")
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("problem")
    }
  }

  const body = editorState.getCurrentContent().getPlainText("\u0001")

  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="post-title" className="text-muted mb-1">
            <small>Title</small>
          </label>
          <input onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)} autoFocus name="title" id="post-title" className="form-control form-control-lg form-control-title" type="text" placeholder="" autoComplete="off" />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="post-body" className="text-muted mb-1 d-block">
            <small>Content</small>
          </label>
          <div className="App">
            <Editor editorState={editorState} onEditorStateChange={handleEditorChange} name="body" id="post-body" className="body-content tall-textarea form-control" type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <button className="btn btn-primary">Save New Post</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default withRouter(TextEditor)
```

**This is the code essentially allowing me to actually display the text on save:**

```
const body = editorState.getCurrentContent().getPlainText("\u0001")
```